# How to force https and www. in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

comI tried following code in .htaccess to force https and www. Because I allways want a URL like https://www.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If i type in these cases into the browser it works fine:

```
www.domain.com
domain.com
http://www.domain.com
http://domain.com
```

But if i type following line - no forwarding happens:

```
https://domain.com
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need these 2 rules for all the redirections:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake by overwriting my original domain (it ends with .biz). For this example it is only domain.com - see the edited question.

Comment: It is the same problem. Everything works fine, but if i type in the https:// without the www. the result is `https://domain.com`

Comment: check updated rules and **make sure to test in a new browser**

Comment: I tried it with the new code, in a new Browser and with cleared cache. Still the same problem.

Comment: These rules are correct and as you can see `https://domain.com` will be redirected to `https://www.domain.com` in 2nd rule above. You have some other rule or conflicting code. You can open firebug and enter `https://domain.com` in browser to see what redirects are you getting in `Net` tab.

Comment: Now I understand the problem. If I type in `https://domain.com` the browser tries to load the certificate first and print a warning that the certificate is only for `www.domain.com` not for `domain.com`. The state in firebug is _aborted_. But if i choose to accept the securtity exception in Firefox, it continous loading with `https://www.domain.com` and the state is 301. But I think i can´t change this behavior that the browser tries first loading the certificate!?

Comment: That behavior cannot be changed since that is done for important security reasons. Certificate exchange between web server and browser happens much before `mod_rewrite` engine is invoked.